# Close modal popup opened using SP.UI.ModalDialog.ShowPopupDialog(url)

Tags: sharepoint-online, modal-dialog, popup, promoted-links

Sharepoint promoted links webpart open in dialog opens the popup using 
`SP.UI.ModalDialog.ShowPopupDialog(url)`

How do I close this popup using a custom button in the popup page
`SP.UI.ModalDialog` is `null` in the context of the page.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try using **commonModalDialogClose**.

Create function to close popup or directly call method.

```
function CloseDlg() {
   SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose(SP.UI.DialogResult.Cancel);
}
```

Or try to hide using class.

```
$('.CloseSPPopUp').click(function(){
   window.top.CloseSPUIPopoup();
});

function CloseSPUIPopoup{
   $(".ms-dlgContent").hide();
}
```

Use **dialogReturnValueCallback** option

```
var options = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();
    options.url = '/_layouts/mySolution/myPage.aspx';
    options.width = 500;
    options.height = 400;
    options.dialogReturnValueCallback = Function.createDelegate(null, CloseCallback);
    SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);


function CloseCallback(result, target) {
    //Your code
}
```

Comment: SP.UI.ModalDialog is undefined. SO it doesn't work

Comment: when you show SP.UI.ModalDialog is defined but when you try to close it is undefined! can not get. Show your code how you are using it

Comment: Can you post some of your code. And have you identify why SP.UI.ModalDialog is undefined? Because at my end its working fine.

Comment: I had to load SP.UI.Dialog.js. But after closing I want to redirect the parent page to another page. How could I do that . Do I need to pass a parameter?

Answer (score 3):

Once I closed my modal in the following way

```
var closeLoading = function() {
    SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function() {
        SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose(1, 1);
    });
};
```

So write the following line of code in your button click handler.

```
SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose(1, 1);
```

Comment: No that doesn't work. SP.UI.ModalDialog is undefined. Is it because popup has been opened using SP.UI.ModalDialog.ShowPopupDialog(url)?

Comment: Show your code. I mean how do you use it

Answer (score 2):

Here is my code for a custom button, in case it helps someone.

```
<input type="button" value="Cancel" name="gobackbutton2" onclick="SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose(SP.UI.DialogResult.Cancel);" />
```